# Returning the key to a randomly selected dictionary value

Tags: python-3.x

I have been asked to build a flashcard program with a dictionary provided giving the keys and values. The idea is to choose a letter to either view the key (word) or the value (definition of the word) and then when you press enter the value is provided to the key and vice versa.

I can randomly generate a key and show the value when hitting enter...

I can randomly generate a value but struggle to show the key when entering

```
#import the random module
from random import *

import csv
file = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')

#define a function for file_to_dictionary
def file_to_dictionary(filename):
    """return a dictionary with the contents of a file"""
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    dictionary = {}
    for row in reader:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
    return dictionary

#set up the glossary
glossary = file_to_dictionary('dictionary.txt')
glossary.values()

#define a function to show a random flashcard
def show_flashcard(): #this is the function header
    """show the user a random key and ask them to define it.
    Show the definition when the user presses return""" # the docstring
    random_key = choice(list(glossary)) #obtain a random key by returning the glossary into a list of keys with list() and choice() for random
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input ('Press return to see the definition')
    print (glossary[random_key])

#define a function to show a random definition
def show_definition():
    """show a random value from the dictionary and ask them to name the word"""
    random_value = choice(list(glossary.values()))
    print ('What word relates to this definition ?', random_value)
    input ('Press return to see the word')
    print (glossary.values[random_value])
```

I get the required results from when I run the code for a random key and then pressing enter to see the value (definition) and also when I run the code for a random value, but then struggle in returning the key to match the value.

Below is the output of the code running correctly and returning an error:

```
Press s to see a flashcard, Press d to see definition, or press q to quit s
Define:  container
Press return to see the definition
(As applied to computing) a cloud technology where the virtualisation happens within the operating system itself; a container is a portable module in which software can be run.
Press s to see a flashcard, Press d to see definition, or press q to quit d
What word relates to this definition ? Legible data unprotected by encryption.
Press return to see the word
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/degsy/Desktop/Python/tet_gloss.py", line 48, in <module>
    show_definition()
  File "/Users/degsy/Desktop/Python/tet_gloss.py", line 37, in show_definition
    print (glossary.values[random_value])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I am brand new to coding and have enjoyed learning python over the last couple of weeks, but this quiz has really baffled me. Appreciative of any help for a complete newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the same value for multiple keys. Getting the key from a value 1 for  `{1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1}` gives 4 possible keys for value of 1.

Probably easiest would be to take a random `key,value` *tuple*  directly when asking and and ask about it:

```
from random import choice
def show_definition(d):
    """show a random value from the dictionary and ask them to name the word"""
    # get a random key,value from .items()
    random_key, random_value = choice(list(d.items()))
    print ('What word relates to this definition ?', random_value)
    input ('Press return to see the word')
    print (random_key)

show_definition(  {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"} )
show_definition(  {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"} )
show_definition(  {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"} )
```

Output:

```
What word relates to this definition ? three
Press return to see the word
3
What word relates to this definition ? one
Press return to see the word
1
What word relates to this definition ? two
Press return to see the word
2
```

See [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: Thank you Patrick - the tuple worked by calling both the random_key, random_value. I had to change the code slightly to make it fit, but it just opened up a whole new understanding to what I can do with dictionaries (which wasn't much to start with).  Works a treat now. Thanks again.